# How do I turn off Omni Complete in Vim?

Tags: vim

Adding `filetype plugin on` to my .vimrc turned on vim's auto complete functionality.  This adds a small delay before you can use a movement without invoking auto complete.  How do I turn this off without removing that line of code which is necessary for pyflakes integration.

2016 edit:
Despite all the useless advice in this thread, the question did eventually get answered on StackOverflow a year later (by Ingo Karkat no less).

[Disable omnicomplete or ftplugin or something in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24931088/)

Comment: It's my config.  The behavior is isolated to "filetype plugin on" (which is what the documentation says http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion).  I don't have any plugins installed.  Maybe take this as an opportunity to re-think how you answer stackoverflow questions?

Comment: **There's no auto completion in Vim.** If you get autocompletion it means that you have a plugin or a piece of script somewhere that does the autocompletion. Simple.

Comment: Technically correct is the best kind of correct, isn't it?  Why be useful or helpful or display anything remotely resembling social skills when you can just be right?  Vim on Ubuntu comes with 1151 scripts installed.  Telling me one of them causes my problem is technically correct but utterly useless, especially since the question was how do I turn off Omni Complete, a core feature of Vim, not how do I delete anything that might possibly use Omni Complete to cause this issue.  Keep it up though.  I'm sure being technically correct makes you feel good about yourself.

Comment: You come here to ask for technical help: "technically correct" is the best kind of "correct" you could expect. No, there's no auto completion in Vim. If you type `foo` and Vim automatically suggests a few completions after you type the second `o` it means that you have a third party plugin or some custom script listening. If you don't know what plugin in your setup could do that it means that you don't know what plugins are in your setup which is utterly wrong. How can you expect us to help you if you don't provide a minimum of helpful information?

Comment: I have a plugin that provides auto completion in my setup. It's called AutoComplPop and I know what it does and how it does it because I've tested all the similar offerings available at the time before chosing this one. Because I actively and explicitely installed and enabled an auto completion plugin I *can't* find myself in a situation where I think "wow! what happened? why do I have this completion popup?". That would be quite frightening. If you have auto completion, it comes from a plugin/script. If you don't want auto completion, delete that plugin/script.

Comment: But [it appears](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513218/how-do-i-turn-off-omni-complete-in-vim#comment20257149_14517463) that completion is not automatic anymore but triggered by `<C-c>k`. And we enter WTF land. Why did you say it was automatic to begin with? Why on earth would omni completion be triggered by `k` in *normal* mode which is where you should be after hitting `<C-c>` in *insert* mode? Why would you want to disable a feature that does nothing if you don't invoke it? Why didn't you follow up on Ingo's `:verbose …` comment which would have helped you and us a lot? WTF indeed.

Comment: Omnicompletion is built-in, you could probably rebuild Vim without it but what would be the point? it is completely passive and does no harm unless you type awkward key combos. The only practical way to "disable" it is to not use it. Because Vim *can't* do auto completion by itself or doesn't use that weird `<C-c>k` mapping you must look for the script that either provides auto completion or defines that weird mapping. Because we have no idea what's in your config, your statements are mutually exclusive and you seem reluctant to provide useful informations, a happy ending is doubtful.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as this Kevin.  It sounds like his temper was getting in the way.  When I edit sql, <C-c> has a big annoying delay.  If during that delay I type k then it completes a sql word that I never would have wanted. Typing ":verbose imap <C-c>k" gives me "i  <C-C>k      *@<C-\><C-O>:call sqlcomplete#Map("sqlKeyword\\w*")<CR><C-X><C-O>
        Last set from /opt/local/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/sql.vim"

Any advice?

Answer (score 5):

Vim does not have auto-complete; any completion must be explicitly triggered with `<C-n>` or a `<C-x>` combination.

What you experience is probably a plugin, possibly related to Python. Check what you've installed, read its documentation, and follow the instructions there how to turn it off. It is probably implemented with some autocmds, which can be shut down via `:autocmd! AutoCmdGroupNameHere`, but there should be a configuration variable for it.

Comment: It's triggered by <C-c>k.  It's not limited to Python.  I deleted everything I had installed without affecting the behavior.

Comment: Okay, then `:verbose imap <C-c>k` tells you where it's coming from. And I tell you, this is no default command in Vim.

Comment: So… we went from "auto completion" to "completion on `<C-c>k`. That's progress, I guess.

Comment: @romainl: Yeah, and I wonder who overloads `<C-c>` like this for `k`ompletion?!