# Disable omnicomplete or ftplugin or something in vim

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I am trying to disable (auto-/omni-/whichever-) completion in sql.  It is a problem for me because I used `<C-c>` for escape and when the file end in .sql it seems to initiate some search with a frustrating 2 second pause. In particular, typing `k` during the pause is causing a collision that inserts unwanted sql keywords.

.vimrc has

```
  filetype plugin off
  set omnifunc=
```

and `:filetype` returns `filetype detection:ON  plugin:OFF indent:ON`

but in insert mode `<C-c>k` still prints

```
  -- Omni completion (^O^N^P)
   match 1 of 80` while autocompleting
```

and `:verbose imap <C-c>k` returns

```
i  <C-C>k      *@<C-\><C-O>:call sqlcomplete#Map("sqlKeyword\\w*")<CR><C-X><C-O>
        Last set from ~/projects.vim
```

and `verbose set omnifunc` can be overwritten, even when I `:set omnifunc=` (when I set it to nothing) directly:

```
  omnifunc=sqlcomplete#Complete
        Last set from /opt/local/share/vim/vim74/autoload/sqlcomplete.vim
```

More due diligence:

1. :help omnifunc
2. :help ftplugin
3. This, which is maybe the same, but wasn't answered: [How do I turn off Omni Complete in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513218/how-do-i-turn-off-omni-complete-in-vim)
4. Other SO advice, which is all about turning these features on
5. Changing the filename to have a different suffic solves the problem
   but that is dumb.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those mappings come from `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/sql.vim`. You'll find it documented under `:help ft-sql`. How to customize / turn off the mappings is described under `:help sql-completion-customization` (and following paragraphs). Summary:

If you don't want any of those mappings:

```
let g:omni_sql_no_default_maps = 1
```

To just redefine the annoying key:

```
let g:ftplugin_sql_omni_key = '<Leader>sql'
```

You can also completely disable that key by choosing a nonexisting one:

```
let g:ftplugin_sql_omni_key = '<Plug>DisableSqlOmni'
```

Put any of those into your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: Wonderful.  One extra note: this didn't actually fix my problem because the settings in my session (I use a lot of mksession) were overwriting the settings in .vimrc.  I had to go through the session file and delete every reference to omnifunc before this advice would work, but it did.  <New question; How could I have gotten mksession to be saving the .vimrc settings?>

Comment: Glad I could help! I recommend to `:set sessionoptions-=options`, that will stop storing mappings and options in your sessions, so you won't have those problems in the future (and the stored session becomes much smaller). The option default is bad IMO.

Comment: Thanks for rtfm on this one, I also use <C-c> to exit insert mode, so disabling these bindings makes editing sql files much more pleasant for me.

Comment: @oregonTrail I just run in the very same problem. It was so annoying!

Comment: slimv uses omni as well: you can disable it by opening `ftplugin/slimv.vim` and searching for `<Tab>` and `<S-Tab>` and adding `<Plug>` in front of the keymappings for `SlimvHandleTab()`