# What enabled vim omnicomplete after OSX update?

Tags: macos, vim

Is seems omnicomplete is now installed after some XTools update. I do not have it in my .vim/bundle. How to de-activate this?

Comment: omnicomplete is built into vim. This question doesn't really make sense. `:help compl-omni`

Comment: I guess I was reading this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14513218/how-do-i-turn-off-omni-complete-in-vim ... what is happening is that some horribly slow plugin/functionality is now enabled so that typing dots in python brings up extra screens. It is not yet obvious from the help how to disable this.

Comment: It seems it is jedi-vim plugin. Somehow this was not enabled before the update. Removing the plugin obviously fixes the slow autocompletion feature.